# Remove cart item function working in the other theme perfect except SAVOY, wordpress

Tags: wordpress

**Code**

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_mini_cart_contents', 'action_woocommerce_before_mini_cart', 10, 2 ); 


 function action_woocommerce_before_mini_cart(  ) { 


             $targeted_id = 812;

                // Loop through cart items
                foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) { 
                    if( in_array( $targeted_id, array($cart_item['product_id']) )){
                    $quantity = $cart_item['quantity'];

                    break; 
                    }
                }



                 if( isset( $quantity ) && $quantity > 1 ) {
                        $product_id = 812;
                        $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $product_id );
                        $cart_item_key = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id );
                         if ( $cart_item_key ) WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key ); 

                         }

            }
```

this is my code and it's not working in savoy wordpress theme.Mean while when we use this code in our any other site and in plugin it's working fine. Worried how it will done?

Comment: Add higher priority ?

Comment: By editing your Question can you expand on "it's not working". Please share any error messages.